# Transforming a complex text list

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a large word list in a simple text document (80K words) that goes like this:

```
needy
    needier, neediest, neediness
need
nefarious
    nefariously, nefariousness
negate
    negated, negates, negating
```

I would like to transform it to something like this:

```
needy needy
needy needier
needy neediest
needy neediness
need need
nefarious nefarious    
nefarious nefariously
nefarious nefariousness
negate negate  
negate negated
negate negates
negate negating
```

How would you advise me to do? I can do some php mysql, or I can work on Excel.

Comment: you should hire a programmer to do this for you ;)

Comment: Question: Does it have to be php?  If you have a text editor - that is worth it's salt..  You can do this..
Search for newline and 4 spaces
Replace with 1 space

Comment: What have you tried so far? For a memory efficient/fast way to read the file, I'd use `while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) { ... }` and handle the logic inside. If it doesn't have to be in PHP, use your text editor and a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The code opens your text file and grabs them into an array, splits them into chunks of 2's. It is iterated through a loop and the second array element is exploded using comma and concatenated to the first element and then added to a new array.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$arr = file('stats.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); //<--- Point the filename of your text document
$arr = array_chunk($arr,2);
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1)
{
    $v = explode(',',$arr1[1]);
    foreach($v as $val)
    {
        $new_arr[]=$arr1[0]." ".trim($val);
    }
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/147756)</kbd>

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => needy needier
    [1] => needy neediest
    [2] => needy neediness
    [3] => nefarious nefariously
    [4] => nefarious nefariousness
    [5] => negate negated
    [6] => negate negates
    [7] => negate negating
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It seems to be working except when the word does not have any inflections. In other word, when there is only one word on a line, then it grabs the word right after. I updated the list to show you.